# How can I assign a 1 or 0 to each column in a table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table called `Person` with 15 columns. Depending on the `EventId`, certain columns will be used and certain columns will not be used. For example, an `EventId` of 5 will use the columns `Name`, `Address`, and `Phone`. Meanwhile an `EventId` of 10 will use the columns `Name` and `Email`.

I think I have to make a table with the `EventId` and somehow put a 1 or 0 in to know which columns that particular event should have. However I do not know how to tie all of this together and make it work.

I am using SQL Server.

Comment: Can you add some sample data, and specify 0 or 1 values? BTW, it's generally a bad idea to store values computed from other columns, data inconsistency is a common problem if you do. (Use triggers, views, or "computed columns".)

Comment: You could also have one row for each item (e.g. 5 + Name and 5 + Address), so you wouldn't need to have separate columns for each items, and only store the ones with "1", the missing ones would be "0", but this is just a matter of opinion and depends on your data / use case too

Comment: JamesZ, that would be great. How would I create this row for each item like you say?

Comment: Here is a great place to start getting an answer to your question. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
create table  #test (EventID varchar(max), Name varchar(max), [Address] varchar(max), [Phone] varchar(max))
insert into #test 
values ('1','Abc','gabanes adfga','1521623612'),
       ('3','adz','gabwega abae' ,'1521623612'),
       ('5','qqb','asdhahn ansxeh','1521623612'),
       ('5','qas','smystrj sthshs','1521623612'),
       ('2','qar','sthtr sthsht ','1521623612'),
       ('1','qha','msgnsn abawe ','1521623612')

; with cte as 
(
select *, case when EventID = 5 then 1 else 0 end as Flag from #test 
) 
select Name, [Address], Phone  from cte
where flag = 1

;with cte1
 as ( select *, case when EventID = 5 then 1 else 0 end as Flag from #test )
 select Name, Phone from cte1 
 where flag != 1
```

I have named the columns randomly and just put garbage data into the fields. However, hope this helps achieve what you are trying to do.